# How can I cast and add a unit-of-measure to an existing value in F#?

Tags: casting, f#

I need to cast values to other data types and because the environment deals with meters, seconds, radians, degrees, etc. I am also using units of measure. My problem stems from a dependency on C# code and needing to use it in my project.

This seems like such a trivial problem, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out. It wouldn't be a problem if I could go in and add the units to the original definition, but I need to add them to existing types and existing values.

Here is a demo C# project. The F# project has this as a dependency.

```
namespace test
{
    public class Polygon
    {
        public int angle = 3;
        public int length = 1;
    }
}
```

Here is the F# project with various ways I've failed at casting and adding a unit-of-measure.

```
[<Measure>] type m

open test

let x : int = 1;

// == trying to cast int to float and assign unit-of-measure ==
type a = float<m>
let y:a = a x                 // The value or constructor 'a' is not defined
let y:a = (a)x                // The value or constructor 'a' is not defined
let y:a = upcast (float x)    // Type constraint mismatch. The type 'float' is not compatible with type 'a'
                              //    The type 'a' does not have any subtypes and need not be used as the
                              //    target of a static coercion.
let y:a = downcast (float x)  // The type 'float' does not have any proper subtypes and cannot be used
                              //    as the source of a type test or runtime coercion.
let y:a = float<m> x          // Expected type, not unit-of-measure
let y:a = (float x)<m>        // Unexpected token '>' or incomplete expression
let y:a = (float<m>)(float x) // Expected type, not unit-of-measure

// == trying to only assign unit-of-measure ==
type b = int<m>
let y:b = x      // This expression was expected to have type 'b' but here has type 'int' 
let y:b = x<m>   // Unexpected type arguments
let y:b = (x)<m> // Unexpected token '>' or incomplete expression

// == actual usecase ==
let getLength (shape : test.Polygon) : float<m> =
    float<m> shape.length // ???

let getSides (shape : test.Polygon) : float =
    float shape.angle

let usecase (shape : test.Polygon) =
    let fancySide = getLength shape
    let fancySides = getSides shape
    fancySide + fancySides // Needs to give error
```

Comment: Seems I might have missed the ability to multiply by 1 of a unit to apply the unit. Does this come with a runtime cost? `let y:a = (float x) * 1<m>`   --- let me know if I need to delete my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FloatWithMeasure` for this conversion:

```ml
let y:a = LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure x
```

See [the F# language guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure#conversions) for details:

> To convert a unitless value to a value that has units, you can multiply by a 1 or 1.0 value that is annotated with the appropriate units. However, for writing interoperability layers, there are also some explicit functions that you can use to convert unitless values to values with units. These are in the [FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-languageprimitives.html#FloatWithMeasure) module.